# Solve " Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: Could not load DLL!" for Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

There was a problem starting Android Emulator.The Error I got while starting the Android Emulator by executing the command `emulator-arm @AVD_name` is

`Could not load OpenGLES emulation library:Could not load DLL!`.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At last I got how to start the Android Emulator.I think the problem in windows is that the android emulator while executing points to the `sdk\tools\` directory instead of `sdk\tools\lib` directory as said in [Android-open project Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33336).

The things you have to do is:

1. First copy all the files starting with `lib` and having the extension `dll` from the `sdl\tools\lib`  directory into the `sdk\tools\` directory.
2. If you still can't get the emulator working after copying also place the `-gpu off` option in the command line while executing the command `emulator-arm @AVD_name`.

After doing these two things the Android Emulator started for me.

Comment: Moving the DLLs worked for me. Thanks !   `-gpu off` effectively just kills the error message by disabling GPU emulation, which presumably you're trying to get to work if you have that error message

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler solution: Use 'emulator' instead of 'emulator-arm'.

'emulator' is used to perform a few checks and modify the library load path, to ensure the GPU emulation libraries are found, among other things.

'emulator-arm' is being called by 'emulator' after this. If you want to call it directly, you will have to modify your PATH (or LD_LIBRARY_PATH) variable before doing so. Alternatively, copying the libraries to sdk/tools/ will have the same effect on Windows (but not other platforms). But all this hackery is not necessary when calling 'emulator'.

If for some reason calling 'emulator' doesn't work, please explain why. I'm curious why you would need to call 'emulator-arm' directly.

Comment: :It even works with emulator as you requested.You're answer is too correct while if the OS is Linux but if it's Windows I think that without copying the files as said in the answer you might never get to initialize the OpenGLES library or you can do it by pointing the environment variable to the directory which contains the OpenGLES files.I haven't done the second option.

Answer (score 1):

I use the the BAT script below to start Android emulator on Windows system.

```
emulator_start.bat <AVD_FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION>
```

Content of emulator_start.bat file :

```
@echo off
set AVD_FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION=%1
title Android Emulator %AVD_FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION%
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\lib;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
rem set EMULATOR_CMD=emulator
set EMULATOR_CMD=emulator-arm
%EMULATOR_CMD% -avd %AVD_FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION% -gpu on -no-boot-anim -wipe-data
```

Answer (score 1):

On the menu of Android Studio select :

Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager

It opens a list of the available Virtual Devices . Select the one you are experiencing this problem with . Click on the pencil ( Edit ) icon .

Click the "Show Advanced Settings" button.

Deselect the flag "Use Host GPU" under Emulated Performance.

This worked for me.

My Android Studio version is 1.5.1 .

Answer (score 0):

1- Open --> Android Virtual Device Manager

2- Click on button --> Edit

3- In --> Emulated Performance, Graphics:`[Software - GlES 1.1] <-- Choose`